# Catch JNI exceptions in Java layer

Tags: java, android

I have an Android application that I'm writing, and it uses a module that runs on the JNI layer.
I have no control or knowledge on how the NDK module works, and it sometimes throws an un-handled  exception, and my app crashes.

Is there any way to catch those JNI propagating exceptions in the Java layer? Or at least detect when the DNK is going to crash due to an exception?

Comment: Is the thrown exception class an unchecked one (ie, it inherits `RuntimeException`)?

Comment: I Have no idea. It gives no indication regarding what made it crash, or that indeed there was a crash. On select occasions, it deigns worthy to log signal 6 or 8.

Comment: Huh, your comment makes me doubt whether you see a Java exception at all; can you edit your question and add the relevant logs please?

Comment: your comment suggest you misunderstood my question: My whole point is that I don't see any Java exceptions, the JNI part throws it, and it doesn't reach my Java catch clause before the app crashes. Seeing a Java exception was the result I was hoping to get.

Comment: I didn't misunderstand. The thing is that if the exception is unchecked then you need not catch it and it may propagate up to the main thread unnoticed.

Comment: @fge It can't propagate anywhere, let alone unnoticed, if the application crashes before the Java `catch` clause is reached. You aren't making any sense.

Comment: @EJP read again -- what if the exception is unchecked? Also, this is why I asked for logs; OP did not tell whether the exception actually made it into the logs at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JNI exceptions propagate to the Java layer. The problem is that they only do so when the JNI method returns. In the meantime it may have perpetrated all kinds of self-harm while in an invalid state due to a prior exception. You need to get hold of the JNI source code and fix it, or complain to the vendor/supplier if you can't.

Comment: I thought as much. Still, had some hope. Thanks.